Proof Verification: Supremum and Infimum of $A=\{n+\frac{(-1)^n}n|n\in\mathbb N\}$
Problem
If $A=\{ n + \frac{(-1)^n}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, prove that $A$ is not bounded above but bounded below and $\inf(A)=0$.
My answer
Let $A=B\cup C$ where $B=\{ n - \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}_{\text{odd}}\}$ and $C=\{ n + \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}_{\text{even}}\}$.
Assume that $\sup(B)$ exists and let $u=\sup(B)$. Since $u-1\lt u$, $\exists m\in B$ such that $u-1\lt m\le u$.
$\therefore\exists m_0\in \mathbb{N}_{\text{odd}}$ such that $u-1\lt m_0 - \frac{1}{m_0} \le u$.
$\implies u\lt m_0 +1 - \frac{1}{m_0}\lt m_0 +2 - \frac{1}{m_0+2}\quad(\because\frac1{m_0}\gt\frac1{m_0+2})$.
But $(m_0+2)\in\mathbb{N}_{\text{odd}}$. Let $m'=m_0+2-\frac1{m_0+2}$. Therefore $\exists m'\in B$ such that $m'\gt u$; contradiction.
Therefore the assumption is false.
$\implies B$ is not bounded above.
$\therefore A$ is not bounded above.$\quad\square$
Consider the set $B$.
$\begin{align}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\text{odd}},~n&\ge1\\ \frac1n&\le1\\ -\frac1n&\ge-1\\ \therefore\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\text{odd}},~n-\frac1n&\ge0\\ \therefore\forall x\in B,~x&\ge0\end{align}$
$\implies 0$ is a lower bound of $B$. Therefore $B$ is bounded below and $\inf(B)$ exists.
Let $l$ be any lower bound of $B$. By definition, $\forall x\in B,~x\ge l$.
Since $1\in\mathbb{N}_{\text{odd}}$, $1-\frac11=0\in B$. Therefore $0\ge l$. Since $0$ is also a lower bound of $B$, $0=\inf(B)$.
Now consider the set $C$.
$\begin{align}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\text{even}},~n&\gt0\\ \frac1n&\gt0\\ \therefore\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\text{even}},~n+\frac1n&\gt0\\ \therefore\forall x\in C,~x&\ge0\end{align}$
$\implies 0$ is a lower bound of $C$. Therefore $C$ is also bounded below and $\inf(C)$ exists. And $\inf(C)\ge0$.
Therefore $A$ is bounded below and $\inf(A)=\inf(B\cup C)=0$.$\quad\square$

Is this proof correct? Suggestions on corrections/improvements are highly appreciated. Alternative proofs are also welcomed.

The proof is fine. For a more compact one, notice that, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$n+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\geq n-\dfrac{1}{n}\geq n-1$$
This already proves that the set is bounded below by $0$, and that it is not bounded above (because $n-1\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$).
Now, we have $1-\dfrac{(-1)^1}{1}=0,$ so that $0\in A$. Given that $0$ is a lower bound of $A$, we must have $0=\min(A)$, and consequently $0=\inf(A)$.

Option:
Let $a_n;= n+(-1)^n/n;$
We show
$a_{n+1} > a_n. $
1)$n$ is even:
$n+1/n < n+1 - 1/(n+1)$;
or equivalently:
$1/(n+1) +1/n <1$, for $n=2,4,6...$
This is pretty obvious.
For $n=2$ the inequality is satisfied.
For $n>2$, i.e. $4,6,...$
we have
$1/(n+1)+1/n <1/n+1/n=2/n<1$
2)$n$ is odd:
$n-1/n < n+1+1/(n+1);$
or equivalently:
$-1/n - 1/(n+1) <1. $
Since
$a_1=0$ and
$a_1<a_2 <.... a_k <a_{k+1}... $
We have $\inf (a_n) =\min (a_n)=0;$
$\sup (a_n) $:
$a_n$ is not bounded above.
Can you finish?
